# A Large Equation - Small Puzzle

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle

My brother Yzarc is always trying to be clever.
Today he claims that 2 equals 10w43e25s10e36n31w.
Why does he say that?

Hint:
I asked my brother why he chose this particular expression, and he said it was because

> in one sense, 2 is the largest number.

Hint 2:
When pressed about why this particular location, Yzarc states:

> This Summer is too hot and so I'm taking a vacation

Hint 3:
This equation has nothing to do with coordinates or math. Try a simple but unexpected approach and consider the numbers and letters involved. The only thing Yzarc used to create it was a

> Certain type of book (paper or online)

Hint 4:

> 1=A
>  1n=T
>  1e=10

Hint 5:

> The numbers 2,10,43... correspond to items in a collection. The nature of the collection should be fairly obvious from the letters.

Comment: rot 13 (Jura V frnepurq sbe 41 jrfg naq 53 rnfg, V tbg n erfhyg Rnfg Jrfg Fgerrg juvpu nhgube jnf vafcverq ol riragf va Hxenvar juvpu nyfb cregnvaf gb 2aq uvag.) Is it correct approach??

Comment: Sorry, you do not need a computer or anything remotely so complicated to find the solution; it will be straightforward and clear... once solved.  The book/reference will be needed though. : )

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yzarc claims that 2 equals 10w43e25s10e36n31w, because...

> ...he's talking about **US geography** in his own unique way.

First of all, the numbers here represent:

> the names of **US states when listed alphabetically**. So, 1 represents Alabama, and 2 is Alaska, all the way through to 50 being Wyoming.
>
>  [image: US states numbered alphabetically]

While the letters 'n', 'e', 's' and 'w' more obviously represent:

> **cardinal directions** on a compass (north, east, south and west).

In combination then, for each number-letter pair Yzarc wants us to...

> ...look on a map at the state in that position of the alphabetised list, then move in the direction indicated. We then need to take the first letter of the state we reach.

So 10w43e25s10e36n31w can be interpreted by breaking it down as:

> 10w = West from Georgia = **A**labama = **A**
>  43e = East from Texas = **L**ouisiana = **L**
>  25s = South from Missouri = **A**rkansas = **A**
>  10e = East from Georgia = **S**outh Carolina = **S**
>  36n = North from Oklahoma = **K**ansas = **K**
>  31w = West from New Mexico = **A**rizona = **A**
>
>  Together, these six letters spell **ALASKA**, which is the *second* state in the alphabetical list, hence number 2 as in the puzzle. So '2 equals 10w43e25s10e36n31w' in the sense that you can spell out the name of state number 2 using this method.

To explain the hints in more detail:

> **Hint 1:** '2 is the largest number' in the sense that Alaska is the largest US state by area.
>
>  **Hint 2:** Alaska is the most northerly US state, and hence the climate is colder there - perfect for a break away from the heat.
>
>  **Hint 3:** The 'certain type of book' used by Yzarc is an **atlas**.
>
>  **Hint 4:** '1=A', because the first state alphabetically is **A**labama. '1n=T' because travelling North from Alabama you reach **T**ennessee. '1e=10' because travelling East from Alabama you reach Georgia, the **10**th state in an alphabetical list.
>
>  **Hint 5:** The 'collection' here is the list of US states. A geographical connection was hinted at by the use of the cardinal directions 'n', 'e', 's' and 'w' in the code.

Answer (score 4):

taking

> E = East, W = West, N = North, S = South

we see that

> W = 10 + 31 = 41

> E = 43 + 10 = 53

> N = 36

> S = 25

> So we are net

> 11 in North(36 - 25)(south is subtracted as the direction is opposite) and

> 12 in East (53 - 41)(west is subtracted as the direction is opposite)

Finally,

> Putting these coordinates (11N 12E) in Google Maps, we see that that Plus code of the location is 2222+22. This location is in Nigeria

> Looking at the origins of name yzarc https://www.names.org/n/yzarc/about in International Interest for Yzarc section. I do see some interest in Nigeria in this name.

And so, I believe this why your brother equates it.

Comment: I thought it was just Crazy in reverse

Comment: Your first step is correct.  But since n = north, it does not also equal any numbers.